# Invalid URL | TypeError

Tags: javascript

When clicking the button on my front end (relevant portion shown below)

```
async function getSample() {
  const res = await fetch('/lookup/url');
  const data = await res.text();
  console.log(data);
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', getSample);

async function getSample() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/lookup/url')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

I am getting this error in the terminal of my node server:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: url
```

and this in my console:

```
Fetch failed loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/lookup/url"
```

Can anyone provide some advice as to what I may be doing wrong and how I could fix?

Not that this matters, but backend is express

Adjustment Re: Comments

```
async function getSample() {
    const res = await fetch('/lookup/url');
    const data = await res.text();
      console.log(data);
    
      document.getElementById('button').addEventListener
       ('click', getSample);
    
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/lookup/url')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    }
```

Comment: I think it might be a CORS issue. The frontend isn't in ``localhost:3000``, right?

Comment: @sebasaenz the front end is showing when I access localhost:3000.

Comment: Why do you have two definitions of `getSample()`?

Comment: @Barmar Don't I need to define it, and then use it?

Comment: Are you declaring the same function twice? You don't need to do it, just once is enough

Comment: Function definitions are hoisted, so you can define it before or after you reference it.

Comment: But you have two definitions, and they're different!

Comment: Although they seem equivalent. The second definition is the translation of `await` to explicit promise code.

Comment: But you changed the URL. One has an explicit `http://localhost`, the other omits this so the server will be filled in with the default.

Comment: @Barmar Without the first async function I get the error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function``` How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The second definition doesn't use `await`, so it can't get that error.

Comment: No one said you should just remove the word `async` at the beginning of the first definition. You only need one definition.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure I understand, how would you adjust this then?

Comment: Pick one function definition and use it, delete the other one.

Comment: I recommend the first one.

Comment: @Barmar So if I remove ```async``` from the first, It will be fine?

Comment: NO! You can't use `await` if you remove `async`. Didn't you read the error message?

Comment: Just remove the second definition. I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem, but two definitions for the same function is just wrong.

Comment: @Barmar got it. Can you check what I added to the original post to confirm that is what you mean?

Comment: NO! Get rid of the second definition entirely. Not just the word "async".

Comment: You need `async` at the beginning of the first definition. How many times do I have to say it?

Comment: @Barmar updated. Sorry, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the second definition of `getSample()`. You only need one definition of the function, and it's better to use a relative URL to access resources on the same server as the front end.

```
async function getSample() {
  const res = await fetch('/lookup/url');
  const data = await res.text();
  console.log(data);
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', getSample);
```